# Codeigniter ZIP:How can i include empty folder also?

Tags: php, codeigniter, zip

My folder structure is

```
dir/
   a/test.txt
   b/
```

Codeigniter zip doesnot include empty folder.
How can i include empty folder also?

Comment: Absolutely unclear!..

Comment: Assume my folder structre is

    dir/
       images/child.png
       a/
       b/
         bb/

Codeigniter zip library only includes non empty folders.How can i include all folders.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->zip->add_dir()
```

Permits you to add a directory. Usually this function is unnecessary since you can place your data into folders when using $this->zip->add_data() , but if you would like to create an empty folder you can do so. Example:

```
$this->zip->add_dir('myfolder'); // Creates a folder called "myfolder"
```

From the official doc. It should answer your question.